# Adding sort behaviour to dynamically generated columns

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, columnsorting

**Versions :**

Aapche MyFaces 2.1.14
RichFaces 4.3.5

**Code :**

```
<rich:dataTable var="row" value="#{bean.rowData}"  index="dataIndex">

        <rich:columns value="#{bean.columnData}" var="column" index="ind" sortBy="#{row[column.id].sort}" sortOrder="#{bean.sortOrder[column.id]}">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{column.header}" />
            </f:facet>          
        #{row.value}
        </rich:columns>                 
</rich:dataTable>
```

**Issue :**

We are migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.
As shown in below code snippet , we were using `<rich:columns>` to dynamically generate columns and to add sort feature for the columns.
Since `<rich:columns>` is now removed , we need to use `<c:forEach>` to generate dynamic columns as per
[Dynamic columns with richfaces 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835552/dynamic-columns-with-richfaces-4)

But the issue remains is how to add sort behaviour for the columns.

Is there any alternative available ?

Please help.

**EDIT 1 :**

I am able to get the desired behaviour by below code , as stated in the comments for the question.

```
<rich:extendedDataTable id="masterTable" var="row" value="#{bean.rowData}"  index="dataIndex" render="masterTable">       
    <c:forEach items="#{bean.columnData}" var="column">                     
        <rich:column sortBy="#{row[column.id].sort}" sortOrder="#{bean.sortOrder[column.id]}"> 
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{column.header}" />
                    </f:facet>          
                    #{row.value}
            </rich:column>
    </c:forEach>               
</rich:extendedDataTable>
```

The reason for using `<rich:extendedDataTable>` is , it allows built-in sorting with arrows (for sorting order displaying). 
The above set up is working.
The issue is now , after I click on column header for sorting ,ajax reRendering doesn't seem to work. It requires manual page refresh and then sorted data is shown 
on the page.
I have observed same issue earlier at other place with `<c:forEach>` . When I removed `<c:forEach>` with `<rich:dataGrid>` , it worked. But in this case as per post [Dynamic columns with richfaces 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835552/dynamic-columns-with-richfaces-4),
I have to stick with `<c:forEach>`

**EDI 2 :** 
The ajax rendering issue is observed when sorting is applied to another column than present one . After page is refreshed , sorting for that particular column works fine until another column is applied for sort.

Comment: Is there a problem using sortBy of rich:column? Same as here (only the difference you would use c:forEach with rich:column inside): http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=dataTable&sample=tableSorting&skin=blueSky

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971651/how-to-sort-a-column-in-a-datatable-jsf-2-0/19386833#19386833). It may help.

Comment: @Andrey,@Vasil : Thanks for your inputs . I am able to progress a little bit. I have updated my question accordingly. The issue of rendering still exists

Comment: @VasilLukach : As per your answer on question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971651/how-to-sort-a-column-in-a-datatable-jsf-2-0/19386833#19386833 , how can I add two arrows for sorting if <h:commandLink> is used for sorting

Comment: Like this: `<f:facet name="header"> <h:commandLink value="#{msg.prgId}">  <rich:componentControl target="chTable" operation="sort"> <f:param name="column" value="programCode"/> <f:param value=""/> <f:param name="reset" value="true"/> </rich:componentControl>
<h:graphicImage value="/img/sort_asc.gif" 
style="border: 0px; vertical-align: middle;" rendered="#{chAction.clients.order == 'programCode ASC'}"/> 
<h:graphicImage value="/img/sort_des.gif" 
rendered="#{chAction.clients.order == 'programCode DESC'}" />
</h:commandLink> </f:facet>`

Comment: Sorry it is not enough space for full code of `rich:column`. Idea is use 3 images for 1) sort asc, 2) sort desc, 3) unsort and render it or using EL for build `value` attribute of image based on needed sorting.